# SQL Query on Field Name passed into stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server which takes 3 parameters and returns a list of Orders like this:

```
@fieldToFilter VARCHAR(100), --Will only be 1 of these values 'Order Date', 'Delivery Date' or 'Dispatch Date'
@StartDate DATE,
@EndDate DATE

SELECT 
    o.Number, o.Customer
FROM 
    Order o
WHERE 
    (o.OrderDate > @StartDate) 
    AND (o.OrderDate < @EndDate) 
    AND (SoftDeleted = 0)
```

The problem with the query above is that I have hard-coded the column `OrderDate` in the `WHERE` clause.

What I want to do is use the value in `@fieldToFilter` to determine what column should be filtered on. e.g.

- If `@fieldToFilter` is `Order Date` then filter on the `OrderDate` column
- if `@fieldToFilter` is `Delivery Date` then filter on the `DeliveryDate` column
- if `@fieldToFilter` is `Dispatch Date` then filter on the `DispatchDate` column

What would be the best way to implement something like this?

Comment: M2c - there are fundamentally two approaches here: one that the query optimizer can optimize and one that it can't....  Depending on your requirements the latter may not be acceptable.  The question I would ask is what is motivating the requirement to be able to filter on generic fields?  Implementing three distinct queries (however you feel is most manageable) will provide the best chances for optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I got the syntax right but something like this should work

```
SELECT o.Number, o.Customer
    FROM Order o
    WHERE (@StartDate < case when @fieldToFilter = 'Order Date' then o.OrderDate
                            when @fieldToFilter = 'Delivery Date' then o.DeliveryDate
                            when  @fieldToFilter = 'Dispatch Date' then o.DispatchDate
                            else o.OrderDate end)
    and (@EndDate > case when @fieldToFilter = 'Order Date' then o.OrderDate
                            when @fieldToFilter = 'Delivery Date' then o.DeliveryDate
                            when  @fieldToFilter = 'Dispatch Date' then o.DispatchDate
                            else o.OrderDate end) 
    and (SoftDeleted=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started. Just replace the other two SELECT statements with the appropriate filters.

```
IF @fieldToFilter = 'Order Date'
BEGIN
    SELECT o.Number, o.Customer
    FROM Order o
    WHERE (o.OrderDate > @StartDate) and (o.OrderDate < @EndDate) and SoftDeleted=0)
END
ELSE IF @fieldToFilter = 'Delivery Date'
BEGIN
    SELECT '2'
END
ELSE IF @fieldToFilter = 'Dispatch Date'
BEGIN
    SELECT '3'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible ways of doing it.

1 - You pass the column name to procedure and build the query dynamically .

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Get_Data
 @fieldToFilter SYSNAME --Will only be 1 of these values 'Order Date', 'Delivery Date' or 'Dispatch Date'
,@StartDate     DATE
,@EndDate       DATE
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
   Declare @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Sql = N' SELECT o.Number, o.Customer
              FROM [Order] o
              WHERE (o.'+QUOTENAME(@fieldToFilter)+' > @StartDate) 
                and (o.'+QUOTENAME(@fieldToFilter)+' < @EndDate) 
                and (SoftDeleted=0) '

  Exec sp_executesql @Sql
                    ,N'@StartDate DATE, @EndDate DATE'
                    ,@StartDate
                    ,@EndDate
END
```

---

2 - You Add paramaeter for each column , set value to 1 for the filter you want to apply , this also gives you the option of applying multiple filter or none at all.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Get_Data
 @FilterOnOrderDate     BIT  = NULL
,@FilterOnDeliveryDate  BIT  = NULL
,@FilterOnDispatchDate  BIT  = NULL
,@StartDate             DATE = NULL
,@EndDate               DATE = NULL
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
   Declare @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Sql = N' SELECT o.Number, o.Customer
              FROM [Order] o
              WHERE (SoftDeleted=0) '
            +  CASE WHEN @FilterOnOrderDate = 1 THEN 
              N' AND (o.OrderDate > @StartDate) 
                 AND (o.OrderDate < @EndDate) ' ELSE N'' END  
            +  CASE WHEN @FilterOnDeliveryDate = 1 THEN 
              N' AND (o.DeliveryDate > @StartDate) 
                 AND (o.DeliveryDate < @EndDate) ' ELSE N'' END  
            +  CASE WHEN @FilterOnDispatchDate = 1 THEN 
              N' AND (o.DispatchDate > @StartDate) 
                 AND (o.DispatchDate < @EndDate) ' ELSE N'' END  

  Exec sp_executesql @Sql
                    ,N'@StartDate DATE, @EndDate DATE'
                    ,@StartDate
                    ,@EndDate
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below will help you out

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = ''

SET @sql = @sql + 'SELECT 
    o.Number, o.Customer
FROM 
    Order o
WHERE (SoftDeleted = 0) '

if @fieldToFilter = 'Order Date'
begin
    SET @sql = @sql + 'AND  (o.OrderDate > @StartDate) AND (o.OrderDate < @EndDate)'    
end 
else if @fieldToFilter = 'Delivery Date'
begin
    SET @sql = @sql + 'AND  (o.DeliveryDate > @StartDate) AND (o.DeliveryDate < @EndDate)'  
end 
else if @fieldToFilter = 'Dispatch Date'
begin
    SET @sql = @sql + 'AND  (o.DispatchDate > @StartDate) AND (o.DispatchDate < @EndDate)'  
end 

exec (@sql)
```